# Rewrite git authored dates with git-python

Tags: python, gitpython

I know git authored dates can be rewritten with `git filter-branch`, but I'd like to know if such a thing is possible using only git-python.

I'd like to avoid having to create scripts at runtime and calling the lowlevel git wrapper of git-python.